# Embed YouTube on site, to open in a NEW PAGE (NOT within the same page)

Tags: youtube

OK, I have thoroughly searched for an answer, and have not found one that WORKS correctly.  I have a page full of videos - listing training videos, each will have a link to a youtube video (all videos have been uploaded to youtube), but will open up in a NEW PAGE on my site.  I am a novice website designer, and the problem seems to be that people are anxious to give me half of the code, rather than being explicit with it. Can you help, please?

Comment: Are you trying to open Youtube.com or have a Youtube video fill an entire page of "YOUR" website?

Comment: Have you tried the possible solutions found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: Your description of the problem is unclear.  Are you embedding the entire YouTube, or a single YouTube video?  By opening in a new page, do you really mean "a new window"?  Your "page is full of videos" and "each [video] will have a link to a youtube video".  What's the difference between a "video" and a "youtube video"?  How are you linking each video to a youtube video?  Including a link to your page, or at least an screenshot with annotations would be good.  You should spend more effort on explaining the problem instead of detailing the hardships of your quest for the correct answer.

Comment: Good points.  This is the link to my page:  http://www.cascademath.com/all_videos_watch.aspx.  Each training video has a CONCEPT (.wmv file) and a PROBLEM (.pdf file).  So far the .pdf files are working as expected.  But the videos do not open as we want them to.  Here is the link to the YouTube page with our videos: http://www.youtube.com/user/CascadeMath.

Comment: This is the code that I have thus far:   <tr>
  <td width="160" valign="middle"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;INT-SUBUS-C</td> 
  <td width="350" valign="middle">Subtraction Unlike Signs (Concepts)</td>
  <td width="155" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/p1Jd3jEbDbQ?list=PLRk0qU9yGCiJKlRgP9DDwgFN6ZirSHW3x" 
onclick="window.open (“http://www.youtube.com/embed/p1Jd3jEbDbQ?list=PLRk0qU9yGCiJKlRgP9DDwgFN6ZirSHW3x”, width="640px", height="390px" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always">INT-SUBUS-C</a></td>

  <td width="156" valign="middle">INT-SUBUS-C</td>
 </tr>

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the **embedding** url.

For instance, instead of: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPx3A6XEUF0

use this: https://www.youtube.com/embed/JPx3A6XEUF0